# Produce a .com instead of a .exe

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

It was required to change the program from ".exe" in".com".

- I removed the stack and data segments because i received errors about their existence.
- I renamed the file in ".com".

But the program doesn't work now (it is displaying nothing). I think it may be due to `movsw`, but I do not understand how it works.

```
.MODEL small
.code
.386

org 100h

Start:

dta         db 128 DUP(?)
dta_hold    db 128 DUP(?)
path        db "*.*",0
LF          db 13,10,'$'
root        db "/",0
line        db "The file with the oldest date of creation: ",'$'

mov es, ax                  ; for movsw
mov ah,3bh
mov dx,offset root          ; Change directory to the root
int 21h

lea dx, dta                 ; dta: disk transfer area
mov ah, 1AH                 ; SET DISK TRANSFER AREA ADDRESS
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT

mov ah, 4EH                 ; FIND FIRST MATCHING FILE
lea dx, path                ; DS:DX -> ASCIZ file specification (may include path and wildcards)
mov cx, 0                   ; file attribute mask
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT

call store_dta

FindNext:

mov ah, 4FH                 ; FIND NEXT MATCHING FILE
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT
jc Finish

; compare filedates & filetimes
lea si, dta_hold            ; DTA of the oldest file
lea di, dta                 ; DTA of the just found file
mov ax, [si+18h]            ; filedate
mov bx, [di+18h]            ; filedate
cmp ax, bx
jc FindNext                 ; just found file is newer
jne Older
; filedates are identical
mov ax, [si+16h]            ; filetime
mov bx, [di+16h]            ; filetime
cmp ax, bx
jc FindNext

Older:                      ; just found file is older
call store_dta              ; copy dta to dta_hold
jmp FindNext

Finish:
call print_filename         ; print the last filename
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

main ENDP

store_dta PROC
mov cx, (128/2)             ; size of DTA in WORDs (half of BYTEs)
lea si, dta
lea di, dta_hold
rep movsw                   ; copy CX times DS:SI => ES:DI
ret
store_dta ENDP

print_filename PROC

lea dx, line                ; new line
mov ah, 09h                 ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT

lea di, dta_hold + 1Eh
mov dx, di                  ; start of filename
_B:                         ; look for NULL (ASCIZ-termination)
cmp BYTE PTR [di], 0
je _F
inc di
jmp _B
_F:                         ; replace NULL by '$'
mov [di], BYTE PTR '$'      ; end-of-string delimiter for INT 21h/09h
mov ah, 09h                 ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT

lea dx, LF                  ; new line
mov ah, 09h                 ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h                     ; DOS INTERRUPT

ret
print_filename ENDP

END Start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .COM-program starts at the beginning of the file, there is no specific entry point. So the first instruction is `dta db 128 DUP(?)` which is no instruction. Move the whole data-block to the end of the program (before the `END Start` directive.

You don't need to initialize `ES` or `DS`, since they are initialized by default to `CS`.But you deleted by accident the `main PROC` line. So replace `mov es, ax ; for movsw` by `main PROC`.

The correct `.MODEL` is 'tiny', not 'small'. Correct the line accordingly.

Add the "tiny"-switch (/t) to your TLINK call.